Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-22. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment
I downloaded JDK23 and currently using Eclipse IDE 2024-09
I have this problem.

Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.
Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-22. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

When I checked build path and my JRE System Library is JDK 23, but I can't find 23 at the compiler tab.
the highest version is 22. What can I do?
I checked build path and saw if JDK 23 is connected. (YES)
but compiler doesn't seem to recognize it.

You need Eclipse 2024-12 for Java 23 support. This is the current release available from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
